# Different Permission levels while Sharing document or folder SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-permissions

I have two SharePoint sites. I am the site collection administrator and I have given one user Manage Permission level on one folder. User can share that folder with others by using 'Share' button. On one site while sharing he is getting the option to select permission level below 'Show Options' link and there are a 5-6 permission levels (Approve,Edit,Contribute etc).
While in the other site he has got the same permission on one folder and while Sharing the folder, he is getting only 'Edit' and 'View' option on the right side and there is no option to select permission levels.
How is this happening? Can someone please let me know the details of this behavior. I need the second site behavior everywhere. the user should not see 10 different permission levels only edit and view. but its not happening on every site.

Please help and suggest How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have unique permission in the folder?

If we don't have permission to manage permission in the site level, there will be have options to let us select permission levels for files/folders in the Share dialog.